# Le mot «simple» a-t-il un autre sens selon le prononciation?

Tags: prononciation

Au lieu de prononcer simple comme "sahmpl", j'écoute un enregistrement en référant à un album comme "sihm pohl"? Est-il un particularité de le locuteur ou existe-t-il deux sens et deux prononciations, un étant individuel(en general ou peut-être en référant à une chanson) et l'autre étant élémentaire?

Answer (score 7):

« Simple » est parfois prononcé à l'anglaise, ce qui correspond à la transcription « sihm pohl », mais c'est plutôt rare.

Sinon, puisque le contexte tourne autour de la musique, il y a peut-être une confusion soit avec « single », soit avec « sample », deux termes anglais toujours prononcés à l'anglaise.

Le premier désignait à l'origine un disque (45 tours) comportant un seul morceau par face, un [single](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_(musique)), contrairement à un album (33 tours) qui comportait de nombreux morceaux (anglais [*Long Play*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_play)). Le concept à été repris plus tard avec les mini-CD / CD.

Le deuxième désigne de courts [échantillons (*samples*)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89chantillon_(musique)) de musique réutilisés pour en composer de nouveaux.

Comment: A-t-il eté prononcé différemment que en anglais aussi. Plus comme "sim p**OH**l"

Comment: Il y a bien sûr des variations régionales et individuelles dans la prononciation mais l'inversion des deux lettres finales n'est pas une caractéristique francophone.

Answer (score 1):

En chanson comme en poésie, il est parfois utile de pouvoir prononcer le 'e' habituellement muet, surtout quand c'est un 'e' final.  Il peut y avoir des variations régionales aussi, mais essentiellement ici je pense qu'il s'agit d'une nécessité de rime.